# when i am creating synonym i am getting following error

Tags: oracle

Enter user-name: scott/tiger

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

```
SQL> create synonym sy1 for tests;
create synonym sy1 for tests
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Comment: Not being sarcastic: what part of "insufficient privileges" is confusing you, exactly? Oracle is a secure system and you can't do anything unless you've been granted the necessary privileges.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is very clear:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-01031: **insufficient privileges**

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm):

> Prerequisites
>
> To create a private synonym in your own schema, you must have the
>   **CREATE SYNONYM** system privilege.
>
> To create a private synonym in another user's schema, you must have
>   the **CREATE ANY SYNONYM** system privilege.
>
> To create a PUBLIC synonym, you must have the **CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM**
>   system privilege.

You need to ask your DBA (or log as priviliged user and run):

```
GRANT CREATE ANY SYNONYM TO scott;
```

Comment: GRANT CREATE ANY SYNONYM TO scott
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges   i  am getting error like this

Comment: and  i also i am getting the same error when creating view                               create view v1 as select * from tests
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges